# How to show wireframes on imported Object / Mesh (.obj file)

Tags: graphics, import, graphics3d, options, mesh

I've managed to import a [Wavefront (.obj)](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/format/OBJ.html) file and store it in a variable like so:

```
model = Import[
    "/path_to_object/my.obj", 
    "Graphics3D", 
    Lighting -> {
        {"Ambient", RGBColor[{0.212, 0.168, 0.2}]},
        {"Directional", RGBColor[{0.8, 0., 0.}], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
        {"Directional", RGBColor[{0., 0.8, 0.}], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
        {"Directional", RGBColor[{0., 0., 0.8}], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}
    }
]
```

The output shows no black edges that you would normally see with `Graphics3D` objects, sort of like a "wireframe overlay". I've tried to call the `Graphics3D` function on `model` in this way:

```
Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[2], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], model}]
```

But I get the error:

```
Graphics is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.
```

I've also tried adding more arguments to the `Import` function but I get the error:

```
Import::argt: Import called with 3 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished? I saw that there is the command `Mesh->All`, but because I'm not that well versed with Mathematica yet, I don't know exactly how to apply a `Mesh` command to an imported `Graphics3D` object.

Comment: Did you want something like `DeleteCases[Import["ExampleData/wrench.obj.gz"], _EdgeForm, Infinity]`?

Comment: @j-m That was fast. How can I mark your comment as the answer? =)

Comment: Another hack for the way my .obj file is imported is: `model /. EdgeForm[] -> EdgeForm[{Thick}]`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At OP's behest:

The easiest approach to see the mesh lines is to remove the `EdgeForm[]` instruction that causes them not to appear. For instance,

```
DeleteCases[Import["ExampleData/wrench.obj.gz"], _EdgeForm, ∞]
```

[image: wrench with a mesh]

As SEngstrom suggests, you can also use a replacement rule. If, for instance, you want a thick gray mesh, here's what you can do:

```
Import["ExampleData/wrench.obj.gz"] /. EdgeForm[] -> EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Gray]]
```

[image: wrench with a gray mesh]

Finally, if you want a true wire frame (no polygons):

```
Import["ExampleData/wrench.obj.gz"] /. EdgeForm[] -> FaceForm[None]
```

[image: wireframe wrench]

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
Import["ExampleData/wrench.obj.gz", "PolygonObjects"] // Graphics3D
```

[image]

You can use the `FaceForm[None]` trick as shown by @J.M. here just as well if you only want the wireframe looks.

Comment: I already showed this somewhere, but cannot find it right now...

Comment: Cool! I forgot you can specify properties in `Import[]`...

Comment: @J.M. `s rather well covered in the docs, too :-)

Comment: Hah, yes. I've gotten too used to `Import["file.ext", filetype, opts]` that I haven't been using the new features that much.

Comment: All right, it was just a comment on this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23543/131